# Lodash differenceBy to only remove once

Tags: lodash

I am trying to get the difference of an array of objects based on a particular key.

Example if I want to remove the first object based on key 'b'

```
const arrayA = [
    {
    a:1,
    b:2
   },
   {
    a:1,
    b:2
   },
   {
     a:11111,
     b:22222,
   }
  ]

  const arrayB = [
    {
    a:"does not matter",
    b:2
   },
   {
     a:"does not matter",
     b:22222,
   }
  ]
```

I want the result to be [{a:1,b:2}]

Using lodash difference seems to remove all occurrences instead of only once.

Answer (score 1):

You convert `arrayB` to a Set of the values of the `b` property. Then filter `arrayA`, and try to delete the value of the `b` of each item from the Set. If the delete is successful (b exists in the Set), the item will be remove, and the `b` value would be removed from the Set as well.

```js
const arrayA = [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":11111,"b":22222}]

const arrayB = [{"a":"does not matter","b":2},{"a":"does not matter","b":22222}]

const bValues = new Set(arrayB.map(o => o.b))
const result = arrayA.filter(o => !bValues.delete(o.b))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If `arrayB` may contain multiple objects with the same value of `b`, and you want to remove an exact number of objects (and not only 1) from `arrayA`, you can use a Map instead. The Map should hold a counter for each value of `b` in `arrayB`. Then filter `arrayA`, and decrement the counter whenever the value of `b` is found. If the counter is `0` or wasn't found, keep the item.

```js
const arrayA = [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":11111,"b":22222}] // 3 x b: 2

const arrayB = [{"a":"","b":2},{"a":"","b":2},{"a":"does not matter","b":22222}] // 2 x b: 2

const bValues = arrayA.reduce((r, o) => r.set(o.b, (r.has(o.b) || 0) + 1), new Map)


const result = arrayA.filter(o => {
  const v = bValues.get(o.b) || 0 // get the current counter of b
  
  if(v === 0) return true // if it's 0 don't remove the item
  
  bValues.set(o.b, v - 1) // decrement the counter
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```